# Show values of custom post meta on 'Add new post' page?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I am developing a website in which I am giving my users a separate profile. Their profile includes a dynamic slider. I made a custom post type named 'Slider' and added all images using:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'slider1', array( image1.png, image2.png ) );
```

I want to show this post meta when Admin adds a new post. Is it possible to use the default 'Add new' page to show the above post meta, or should I make an another menu to show the list of sliders and images?